# Jira: I want to integrate with Service Now and Share Point

Tags: sharepoint, jira, jira-plugin, servicenow, jira-rest-java-api

At present my organization uses SharePoint for demand management and Service Now for incident management.
However I want to bring in Jira as a common tool for demand management, project planning, team collaboration and also incident management.
So I plan to setup connection from the existing SharePoint and Service Now to Jira with the idea to not disturb the existing users of Service Now and Share Point and yet be able to slowly bring in a culture where we use Jira for all purposes.

I want to understand will it incur an additional cost to me ? Let me explain with an example:  N number of users are already on Service Now and reporting incident. Assume none of these N users are on Jira. I create a connection to Jira from Service Now so that these incidents appear on my jira board. All activity on these incidents appear vice versa – A comment put in incident in Service Now appears in corresponding Jira ticket and vice versa.

First question – Can I do this? How?
Second: Do I need my Service Now users to be added to Jira ( which means I need to buy a license for them too even though they will not directly use Jira? Not practical for me – incurs lot of cost as number of users increases and I need to support 2 tools for same user set).

Any feedback/guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: See my reply at about impersonating users using API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268119/service-now-api-how-to-comment-as-specific-user/63800256#63800256

Answer (score 0):

There are two general approaches to this kind of integration: build or buy. You could buy a product such as [ConnectALL](https://www.connectall.com/integration/how-it-works/) to make the connection between Jira, ServiceNow, and SharePoint. This will allow you to get up and running without a lot of development time, though it may not be as flexible as building your own integration.

You can build your own integrations using [web services (REST or SOAP)](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-application-development/page/integrate/web-services/reference/r_AvailableWebServices.html) and [import](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-platform-administration/page/administer/import-sets/concept/c_ImportDataUsingImportSets.html) / [export](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-platform-administration/page/administer/exporting-data/concept/c_ExportData.html) sets. This will give you flexibility to create whatever integration you need between any list / custom table and you will not have to pay for a 3rd party product, but you will need developers to build it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a workflow where a trigger in Service Now appears as an action in your Jira ticket and vice versa, then you can use any integration platforms. With tools like Integromat, IFTTT, automate.io, etc., you don't need to get the support of two tools for the same user sets

Answer (score -1):

ServiceNow has come out with a new module called integration hub, the problem is that it is still in its early stage, and doesn't support bi directional integrations, as well as very pricy product (by transactions).
We have adopted a new product by https://zigiwave.com
the zigiops is perfectly design for any ServiceNow integration in seconds, and with reasonable prices.

https://www.zigiwave.com/